# Heroku build failing: "can't find executable webpack for gem webpacker"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, webpack, webpacker

My Rails/React application is failing when I deploy to Heroku. This was not always the case; it only started happening after reinstalling Webpack locally (for a different project). The app still works fine on my local machine.

I've tried creating a new Heroku app to no avail, and tried reverting to a previous working commit, which also fails now for some reason. There's nothing in the changelog that looks like it would cause any problems except for maybe a change from `webpacker (3.2.0)` to `webpacker (3.3.1)`.

Here's the related part of the Heroku build log:

```
/tmp/build_f18e594f7966bd80b565c49de7015c56/zerovolts-kanjibenkyo-9786c55/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:432:in `block in replace_bin_path': can't find executable webpack for gem webpacker (Gem::Exception)
from /tmp/build_f18e594f7966bd80b565c49de7015c56/zerovolts-kanjibenkyo-9786c55/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:463:in `block in replace_bin_path'
from ./bin/webpack:21:in `<main>'
```

Full build log [here](https://gist.github.com/zerovolts/abc43bd85a8704d1dc70db02a256c65d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can't find executable webpack for gem webpacker (Gem::Exception)

Basically, the executable `bin/webpack` is missing.

The easiest way is to run `rails new app --webpack` and go to the newly created app directory and go to `app/bin` directory and copy those missing files into your own project.

let me know if this fixes your issue

Comment: To clarify, `bin/webpack` wasn't missing, it just seems to have been for an older version of webpack (3.2.0). But copying the code from a newer project fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I see. Good to know.